# Disable a button for a period of time, even if the app is exited

Tags: android

How can I disable button for let's say 30 minutes? I was trying this:

```
 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     btn.setEnabled(false);
     btn.setText("fdfjhsn" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     btn.setEnabled(true)
 }
}.start();
```

But this doesn't work as I wanted. When I change the activity and come back to this one with countdown the button becomes enabled. 
Can you tell me how I can block button for real time, independent of what user does? Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few faults in your logic here:

- `new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)` will countdown 30,000 milliseconds, which is 30 seconds
- The timer will stop and restart when you exit the app because you're not persisting the value anywhere

What you need to do is, when you wanna start the 30 min period, save the current time in a `SharedPreference`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putLong("time", currentTime);
editor.apply();
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

And now whenever you want return to the app (in `onCreate` and `onResume`) retrieve that value and check if more than half hour had passed in the meanwhile:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 long previousTime = prefs.getLong("time", 0);
 long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
// 30*60*1000 - 30 min, each with 60 sec, each with 1000 millisec
if (currentTime - previousTime > 30*60*1000){
 //enable the button
 btn.setEnabled(true);
} else {
 //disable it and start a new CountdownTimer; this is needed in order for
 //it to to become enabled if you're still in the app and the time ran out
 btn.setEnabled(false);
  new CountDownTimer(currentTime - previousTime, 1000){
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
      btn.setText("fdfjhsn" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
      }

     public void onFinish() {
         btn.setEnabled(true)
     }
}.start();
```

Comment: That is what i was looking for. Thank you

Comment: If user clear app data, Button can click again right ? The OP should store time in server.

Comment: You can never completely prevent the user from "hacking" the way around it. I usually just change the time on my phone to be able to play the game more if I want, no need to even delete the data. This is the best I know in offline mode.  Introducing server can be avoided by just turning off the internet. And it would really annoy the users if you told them they needed the internet connection at all times if the app does not quite require it.

Answer (score 0):

Save timestamps from/to to persistence, for example to Shared Preferences. Next time when you start an activity, just check the "disabled-to" timestamp.